# Can I use TFS 2017 to build a project in SVN?

Tags: .net-core, svn, tfs, tfs-2017

We have our source code (ASP.NET Core) within a SVN repository. Now for Continuous Integration, we want to use TFS to build and deploy to Azure WebApp. We can't migrate our code to TFS.

Is this possible?

Comment: What version of TFS are you talking about?

Comment: We use TFS 2017

Answer (score 2):

Subversion is a natively supported repository type when defining builds since TFS 2015 Update 1. You should be able to choose it on the "Repository" tab.

[There is a walkthrough available on VisualStudio.com.](https://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/integrations/subversion)

Comment: I configured it like discribed. But when I want to add a build into the queue, I get following error: 
No agent could be found with the following capabilities: svn, msbuild, visualstudio, vstest.

I already googled this error message. They said I have to add a new agent. Why? I already have an agent for all my other projects which works... 
But I tried to add a new agent, but with running the config.cmd it cannot be connected to the server url..

Comment: Do you have those things installed on your build agent? If not, install them and then restart the agent service so the capabilities are updated. You don't need a new agent.

Comment: The agent, that means my svn repository? I can't install any additional software on it..

Answer (score 2):

You can build code you manage in Subversion in TFS 2017. You must install the Subversion client on your [build agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/agents#install). Check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository#subversion

In the Repository of Build Definition, choose **Subversion** type:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. After reinstalling TortoiseSVN with the command-line tools selected, and then running `config.sh remove` and then `config.sh` on my agent host, svn checkouts and builds now work as expected.